# Redirect Sound output to a specific port...Realtek?

Tags: sound, port-forwarding, audio-jack

I am nearly as much of a noob about Linux/Ubuntu as one can be... currently dual booting side-by-side with Win 7 Pro 64 bit. That being said... system has a 5.1 surround sound card. The main regular port (green) used if you have one analog plug doesnt work properly with Windows....Realtek HD Audio drivers provide a simple work around... just plug said analog plug into another one of the 5.1 ports (say, blue). Then assign the port as "Front Speakers".

That works fine for Windows 7. How do I do the same reassignment/redirect for Ubuntu? I have no sound at this point and the computer is near inaccesible (wires go through the floor to the basement where the computer is) so switching cables back and forth isnt much of an option...

Thanks in advance for any viable help.

Comment: Why is this such a common problem?  I have the same thing, realtek board with 6 outputs, and the main line out (green) all of a sudden went to shit after a while.  Are we all just wearing this port out by using it too much?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to remap the channels on your soundcard?

You can write your own pulseaudio profile-set for your sound card. See my post about this on ubuntuforums.org:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12151686&postcount=13

### This was for my sound card

Save the code as /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/native-instruments-komplete-audio6.conf

```
[General]
auto-profiles = no

[Mapping main-stereo-out]
description = Main stereo output
device-strings = hw:%f,0
channel-map = front-left,front-right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3
direction = output

[Profile output:stereo]
description = Main Stereo Output
output-mappings = main-stereo-out
input-mappings =
priority = 80
skip-probe = false
```

and create a new file for udev rules, for example

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/89-pulse-komplete-audio.rules
```

and paste the following (but replace the xxxx and yyyy with correct hardware ids, you can list them with lsusb):

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="yyyy", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="native-instruments-komplete-audio6.conf"
```

From what I see the idVendor for Native Instruments is 17cc. You can see the existing configurations for other NI cards in /lib/udev/rules/90-pulseaudio.rules file.

After you have created these two files, disconnect your card, run

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Comment: Please include all of the major steps from the link. Should the linked site go down, or the post be deleted, your post would be worthless.